# How to build a recommender system with sales data using python?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine

I have a last year retail sales data. Now I'm interested to build a recommender system based on the last year sales data.

Customer A bought product Ids 1,2,3,4
Customer B bought products ids 2,3,5
Customer C bought product ids 6,2,7,3

In the above data set all the customers bought product Id 3 when they purchase product id 2

So which Machine learning method I have to use create a recommender system.

Note : I'm gonna build tensorflow lite model by using python and keras

Answer (score -1):

Look for the apriori algorithm or any other which can generate association rules.